# Can $pdo->lastInsertId($seqname) be trusted?

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

When using PostgreSQL, I'm forced to pass the name of the sequence to lastInsertId(). Which made me think the query didn't come back from the database with the id, and instead lastInsertId($seqname) is performing an extra query, possibly being prone to a race condition (if another row is inserted at the same time, I will get a wrong result).

Reading the docs I found this comment, which shows the same thought: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php#83440. It's 5 years old, and I couldn't find anything more recent.

What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this to be reliable you must:

- Insert only one record at a time;
- Specify the sequence name; and
- Do the follow-up query on the same session, either by using session level connection pooling, or by using transaction-level pooling and doing both the insert and  `lastInsertId` within the same transaction.

It would be much, *much* better for PDO to use `INSERT ... RETURNING` and get the inserted ID(s) from the result set. That way you'd get a sane value when you did:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(col1,col2)
VALUES (1,'a'),  (2,'b'),  (3,'c')
RETURNING id;
```

With `lastInsertId` you'll get only the ID of the last row inserted - and you *cannot* assume that the prior rows got contiguous IDs. If `lastInsertId` is `42`, there is *no* guarantee that the previous rows are `41` and `40` as there could be concurrent inserts also claiming IDs.

So the answer to "is `lastInsertId` safe" is ... kinda. It's safe if used within the constraints that're required for correct use of `currval`, but it's far from ideal. Personally I'd avoid it and use `INSERT ... RETURNING` instead.

Comment: Wow, now this is an answer! So the gotcha in my case is when using transaction-level pooling, I have to be careful there. I can't really use lastInsertId() without a $seqname though, not sure why, so I'm not gonna fall for that. Thanks!

Comment: I thought about using `returning`, but the insert syntax is annoying since I have to specify field by field. I'll stick to lastInsertId for now.

Answer (score 2):

I bet it uses `SELECT currval('seq_name')`, which returns last generated per connection. So it can be trusted.

Comment: "per connection". What if I'm using a pool? (pgbouncer)

Comment: You get a connection from the pool, and use only that connection.

Answer (score 1):

Sequences' the **only** purpose is to keep consistency.

Otherwise they would be useless.

Comment: I can see how they would keep consistency when inserting, but it's not clear whether this will work for anything else (like finding out in my application, not in the db, what was inserted). Are you sure this will work fine? Even if I'm using a pool? (pgbouncer)

Comment: Again: if it were not working, it would no exist at all. Please, don't take yourself the **only** one who understands the problem. There are 1000s developers who are using this function.

Comment: Again: Do you *know* it works, or you just used "your common sense" and assumed everything works fine because lots of people use it?